# add colum discount on cart table woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

hello I want to add a column in the cart table with the discount percentage
can you help me?

I have this code for the product page

```
////__________________________________________________________________________________________////
//AGREGA EL PORCENTAJE DE DESCUENTO JUNTO AL PRECIO MAYORISTA
// Only for WooCommerce version 3.0+
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = ' ' . __(' (-', 'woocommerce' ) . $percentage . __(' )', 'woocommerce' );
    $price = '<del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) . $percentage_txt : $sale_price . $percentage_txt ) . '</ins>';
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to add a column to the cart page with values depending on the cart item is to override the `cart.php` template.

From the WooCommerce plugin, copy [`woocommerce/cart/cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php)  to `yourTheme/woocommerce/cart/`. If you are not using a child theme, I suggest you create a child theme and override templates through that so in the case your theme gets updated, your template changes won't be be lost. More on [child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

From there you can look through the `cart.php` for where you want to insert the header for the discount percentage, and also insert the data (in this case the discount in percentage).

To get the label for the table header, it's simple. Just add the HTML for the label in the `thead` of the table. In my example, this is found in `cart.php  line 51-59`:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="product-name" colspan="3"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <th class="product-discount"><?php esc_html_e( 'Discount', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th> // added this line
    <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <th class="product-subtotal"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

[There will then be a discount label in the head of the table in the cart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy63b.png)

To get and display the discount percentage, you'll have to go through the template and find the correct location for it. In my example, I will put it in between the price and quantity, directly under the discount heading. In `cart.php`, this would be `line 102`. From there you can just write the HTML and PHP code to calculate the percentage based on the cart items regular price and sale price:

```php
<td class="product-discount">
    <?php
     if($_product->get_sale_price() != ''){
        $reg_price = $_product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = $_product->get_sale_price();
        $percentage = ((($sale_price / $reg_price) - 1) * -1) * 100 . "%";
        echo $percentage;
        }
      ?>
</td>
```

[You can now see that on the cart page it shows the discount percentage based on the cart item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNcmT.png) In my example, the top product is on sale and bottom product is not on sale.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your answer so much.

Despite the fact that I followed all the steps that you indicated, I could not get the percentage to appear in the Discounts column.
I am attaching images in case there is something I did wrong but I think the problem is with the printing of the result in my column.

[add column header][1]

[add the php code][2]

[this is the result][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVhe8.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwHEN.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHsXL.png

Comment: It's unclear exactly what the issue is from first glance. Looks like you have it correct from the images. In order to debug this, I recommend using `var_dump($_product->get_sale_price())` outside of the if statement to see what value you get. If nothing useful comes up, you can try `var_dump($_product)` to see what properties are on the product object. What type of products are these? The code will need to be altered to handle different types of products.

Comment: resolved!
This is how my code looks:

 if($_product->get_price() != ''){
        $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = $_product->get_price();
        $percentage =  round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
        echo $percentage;
        }

thank you so much